# I cannot get full response body using okhttp

Tags: java, string, okhttp

I cannot get full body from the url:

```
view-source:https://www.instagram.com/blackpink_jennie/
```

My source code is

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful())
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                Log.d("haha2","contents length: " + responseBody.contentLength());
                StringBuffer resultString = new StringBuffer(responseBody.string());
                Log.d("haha2", resultString.toString());

                callback.onResponse(resultString.toString());
            }
        }
```

My expectation is to see a full sized body. for example,

> `from <!DOCTYPE html> to </html>`

However, I can only see about 30% of body.

Is it because of java string size?

Comment: can you provide the length of the response String?

Comment: @vatsalmevada it is -1